# Python Polars Window Function With Literal Type

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

Say I have a DataFrame with an id column like this:

```
┌─────┐
│ id  │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 1   │
│ 1   │
│ 1   │
│ 2   │
│ 2   │
│ 3   │
│ 3   │
└─────┘
```

I want to aggregate a running count over the id column, giving this result:

```
┌─────┬───────┐
│ id  ┆ count │
│ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1     │
│ 1   ┆ 2     │
│ 1   ┆ 3     │
│ 2   ┆ 1     │
│ 2   ┆ 2     │
│ 3   ┆ 1     │
│ 3   ┆ 2     │
└─────┴───────┘
```

My attempt involved creating a dummy column, which I think produced the desired result but seems a bit hacky.

```
(
    df.with_columns(
        pl.lit(1).alias("ones")
    )
    .with_columns(
        (pl.col("ones").cumsum().over("id")).alias("count")
    )
    .drop("ones")
)
```

However when I try this:

```
(
    df.with_columns(
        (pl.lit(1).cumsum().over("id")).alias("count")
    )
    .drop("ones")
)
```

I get the error "ComputeError: the length of the window expression did not match that of the group".

Is there a better way to do this? What am I missing in my attempt above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cumcount](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cumcount.html#polars.Expr.cumcount) seems to do the job with a 1-shift adjustment (or any shift you want, of course).

There is also [arange](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.arange.html#polars.arange):

```
df.with_columns(
   count = 1 + pl.col('id').cumcount().over('id'),
   count2 = pl.arange(1, 1 + pl.count()).over('id')
)
```